# values as column headers in snowflake sql

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have a table called `catcounts` with fields `reportDT, category_nm, counts`

records are as follows:

```
 2023-08-01, S1, 100;
 2023-08-01, S2, 50;
 2023-08-01, S0, 101
```

ReportDT value is same for all these rows. I want to convert these into column headers: `reportDt, S1, S2, S0` with values as `2023-08-01,100,50, 101`.

I am unable to use Pivot because I cannot hardcode values and no stored procedure or UDFs. is there a way to do this using CTEs? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot "hardcode" anything, aka you do not know if the `category_nm` will only have values `s0, s1, s2` AND you are not prepared to use Dynamic SQL, then there is nothing you can do to solve this problem.

If the values of the columns where known, then you could use a pivot, thus that cannot be the case. And CTE's will do nothing for you.

So it seems you are unhelp-able.

But if you can use [Snowflake Scripting](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/index) (Dynamic SQL) you can query the table, find the distinct values and build dynamic SQL which will "work for your data".

### Snowflake Scripting:

```
create table catcounts (reportDT date, category_nm text, counts number);

insert into catcounts values
    ('2023-08-01', 'S1', 100),
    ('2023-08-01', 'S2', 50),
    ('2023-08-01', 'S0', 101);
```

so manually what we are targeting is:

```
select *
from catcounts
pivot(sum(counts) for category_nm in ('S0', 'S1', 'S2'));
```

[image]

```
select listagg(distinct '\'' ||category_nm || '\'', ',') 
from catcounts 
where category_nm is not null;
```

[LISTAGG](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/listagg) gives us the column id's we are looking for:

[image]

so if we glue that together with a dynamic sql block, call the built up SQL and return the results:

```
DECLARE 
 ids text;
 results RESULTSET;
BEGIN
    select listagg(distinct '\'' ||category_nm || '\'', ',') into ids from catcounts where category_nm is not null;
    
    let full_sql text := 'select * from catcounts pivot(sum(counts) for category_nm in (' || ids || '))';
    
    results := (execute immediate full_sql);
    return table(results);
END;
```

we get:

[image]

And if we need those order'ed we can use:

```
listagg(distinct '\'' ||category_nm || '\'', ',') within group (order by '\'' ||category_nm || '\'', ',')
```

which might be more readable like:

```
select listagg(cn, ',') within group (order by cn) 
from (
    select distinct '\'' ||category_nm || '\'' as cn 
    from catcounts 
    where category_nm is not null
);
```

so:

```
DECLARE 
 ids text;
 results RESULTSET;
BEGIN
    select listagg(cn, ',') within group (order by cn) into ids 
    from (
        select distinct '\'' ||category_nm || '\'' as cn 
        from catcounts 
        where category_nm is not null
    );

    let full_sql text := 'select * from catcounts pivot(sum(counts) for category_nm in (' || ids || '))';
    
    results := (execute immediate full_sql);
    return table(results);
END;
```

[image]

Comment: I would like to know your dynamic sql approach to this. Could you please provide some insight into it? Thanks

Comment: That worked. Appreciate your time writing it and providing the script for me. Thank you

Comment: @user19184678 If you could be so kind as to accept my answer then (the tick on the left) and prehaps upvote it. That would be appreicated.